# How to add HttpSessionListener for ShiroSession in embedded Jetty server?

Tags: java, shiro, httpsession

I am working on a application which supports both SimpleSession and HttpSession. There is already implemented SessionListener for SimpleSession but that is not working for Http Sessions. The application is using embedded Jetty server. The existing implementation for SimpleSession is mentioned below-

```
    getShiroSessionManager().getSessionListeners().add(new org.apache.shiro.session.SessionListener() {
    /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
    @Override
    public void onStart(Session session) {
       LOGGER.info("Session started : " + session.getId());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void onExpiration(Session session) {
      LOGGER.info("Session expired : " + session.getId());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void onStop(Session session) {
        LOGGER.info("Session stopped : " + session.getId());
    }
    });
    /**
     * Gets the shiro session manager.
     * 
     * @return the shiro session manager
     */
    private static AbstractValidatingSessionManager getShiroSessionManager() {
    SessionsSecurityManager ssm = (SessionsSecurityManager) SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager();
    return (AbstractValidatingSessionManager) ssm.getSessionManager();
  }
```

I want to track also my HttpSession. How can I implement like this for Shiro Http Sessions?

Comment: We need a little more info.  How are you initializing Shiro in you environment?  There are a few ways to do this (programmatically, annotations, web.xml, etc)

Comment: I am using Jetty server so I already setup that via org.apache.shiro.config.Ini class programmatically.

Comment: Can you share a snippet of that code?